# Is it possible to share xrdp session local/remotely in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: remote, session, xrdp

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 and got the xrdp server running and i am able to connect remotely.
I need to use the same session when i connect localy and remotely. I only found info about using it with vnc, is it possible with xrdp?

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know, it's **not possible to share local and remote session through xRDP**. It seems that by design since the introduction of xorgxrdp backend module....

As you mentioned, the only option to access a running session (i.e. sharing) would be to use VNC software.  By the way, you could combine XRDP and VNC to access a share console.  you can check this quite old post (https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956 that might help you visualizing the possible workaround....

Hope this help
Till next time